# How do I uninstall gnome-extra?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, manjaro

I come from an Ubuntu background.

So I ran the following command: "sudo pacman -S gnome gnome-extra --needed" and I get this output:

```
:: There are 40 members in group gnome:
:: Repository extra
   1) baobab  2) empathy  3) eog  4) epiphany  5) evince  6) gdm  7) gnome-backgrounds  8) gnome-calculator  9) gnome-contacts  10) gnome-control-center  11) gnome-desktop  12) gnome-dictionary  13) gnome-disk-utility
   14) gnome-font-viewer  15) gnome-icon-theme  16) gnome-icon-theme-extras  17) gnome-icon-theme-symbolic  18) gnome-keyring  19) gnome-screenshot  20) gnome-session  21) gnome-settings-daemon  22) gnome-shell
   23) gnome-shell-extensions  24) gnome-system-log  25) gnome-system-monitor  26) gnome-terminal  27) gnome-themes-standard  28) gnome-user-docs  29) gnome-user-share  30) grilo-plugins  31) gucharmap  32) mousetweaks  33) mutter
   34) nautilus  35) sushi  36) totem  37) tracker  38) vino  39) xdg-user-dirs-gtk  40) yelp

Enter a selection (default=all): 
warning: baobab-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: eog-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: evince-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gdm-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-backgrounds-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-calculator-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-contacts-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-control-center-3.12.1-3 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-desktop-1:3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-dictionary-3.10.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-disk-utility-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-font-viewer-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-icon-theme-3.12.0-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-icon-theme-extras-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-icon-theme-symbolic-3.12.0-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-keyring-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-screenshot-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-session-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-settings-daemon-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-shell-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-shell-extensions-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-system-log-3.9.90-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-system-monitor-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-terminal-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-themes-standard-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-user-docs-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-user-share-3.10.2-3 is up to date -- skipping
warning: mousetweaks-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: mutter-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: nautilus-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: sushi-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: totem-3.12.1-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: tracker-1.0.4-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: vino-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: xdg-user-dirs-gtk-0.10-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: yelp-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
:: There are 42 members in group gnome-extra:
:: Repository extra
   1) accerciser  2) aisleriot  3) anjuta  4) bijiben  5) brasero  6) cheese  7) devhelp  8) evolution  9) file-roller  10) five-or-more  11) four-in-a-row  12) gedit  13) gnome-chess  14) gnome-clocks  15) gnome-color-manager
   16) gnome-devel-docs  17) gnome-documents  18) gnome-getting-started-docs  19) gnome-klotski  20) gnome-logs  21) gnome-mahjongg  22) gnome-maps  23) gnome-mines  24) gnome-music  25) gnome-nettool  26) gnome-nibbles  27) gnome-photos
   28) gnome-robots  29) gnome-sudoku  30) gnome-tetravex  31) gnome-weather  32) iagno  33) lightsoff  34) nautilus-sendto  35) orca  36) polari  37) quadrapassel  38) rygel  39) seahorse  40) swell-foop  41) tali  42) vinagre

Enter a selection (default=all): 
warning: accerciser-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: aisleriot-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: anjuta-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: brasero-3.11.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: cheese-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: devhelp-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: evolution-3.12.5-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: file-roller-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: five-or-more-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: four-in-a-row-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gedit-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-chess-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-clocks-3.12.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-color-manager-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-devel-docs-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-documents-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-getting-started-docs-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-klotski-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-mahjongg-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-mines-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-nettool-3.8.1-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-nibbles-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-photos-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-robots-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-sudoku-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-tetravex-3.12.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gnome-weather-3.12.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: iagno-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: lightsoff-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: nautilus-sendto-3.8.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: orca-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: quadrapassel-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: rygel-0.22.2-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: seahorse-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: swell-foop-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: tali-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: vinagre-3.12.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Packages (17): farstream-0.2.4-1  libchamplain-0.12.7-2  libdmapsharing-2.9.23-1  libnice-0.1.7-1  libwnck3-3.4.9-1  libxres-1.0.7-1  telepathy-farstream-0.6.2-1  telepathy-idle-0.2.0-1  bijiben-3.12.2-1  empathy-3.12.5-1
               epiphany-3.12.1-2  gnome-logs-3.12.2-1  gnome-maps-3.12.2-1  gnome-music-3.12.2.1-1  grilo-plugins-0.2.12-2  gucharmap-3.12.1-1  polari-3.12.2-1

Total Download Size:    3.02 MiB
Total Installed Size:   42.46 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages ...
 libxres-1.0.7-1-x86_64                                                                                                 7.2 KiB  7.06M/s 00:00 [########################################################################################] 100%
 grilo-plugins-0.2.12-2-x86_64                                                                                        229.2 KiB   563K/s 00:00 [########################################################################################] 100%
 gucharmap-3.12.1-1-x86_64                                                                                           1313.8 KiB   616K/s 00:02 [########################################################################################] 100%
 bijiben-3.12.2-1-x86_64                                                                                              389.8 KiB   558K/s 00:01 [########################################################################################] 100%
 gnome-logs-3.12.2-1-x86_64                                                                                           399.2 KiB   433K/s 00:01 [########################################################################################] 100%
 gnome-maps-3.12.2-1-x86_64                                                                                           117.3 KiB   414K/s 00:00 [########################################################################################] 100%
 libdmapsharing-2.9.23-1-x86_64                                                                                        92.1 KiB   545K/s 00:00 [########################################################################################] 100%
 gnome-music-3.12.2.1-1-x86_64                                                                                        315.6 KiB   507K/s 00:01 [########################################################################################] 100%
 telepathy-idle-0.2.0-1-x86_64                                                                                         53.0 KiB   496K/s 00:00 [########################################################################################] 100%
 polari-3.12.2-1-x86_64                                                                                               179.6 KiB   373K/s 00:00 [########################################################################################] 100%
(17/17) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                               [########################################################################################] 100%
(17/17) checking package integrity                                                                                                             [########################################################################################] 100%
(17/17) loading package files                                                                                                                  [########################################################################################] 100%
(17/17) checking for file conflicts                                                                                                            [########################################################################################] 100%
(17/17) checking available disk space                                                                                                          [########################################################################################] 100%
( 1/17) installing libnice                                                                                                                     [########################################################################################] 100%
Optional dependencies for libnice
    gstreamer [installed]
    gstreamer0.10 [installed]
( 2/17) installing farstream                                                                                                                   [########################################################################################] 100%
Optional dependencies for farstream
    gst-plugins-good [installed]
    gst-plugins-bad [installed]
( 3/17) installing telepathy-farstream                                                                                                         [########################################################################################] 100%
( 4/17) installing libchamplain                                                                                                                [########################################################################################] 100%
( 5/17) installing empathy                                                                                                                     [########################################################################################] 100%
To use Empathy you need to install at least one Telepathy connection manager.
Optional dependencies for empathy
    telepathy-gabble: XMPP/Jabber support
    telepathy-idle: IRC support [pending]
    telepathy-salut: Link-local XMPP support
    telepathy-rakia: SIP support
    telepathy-haze: libpurple support
( 6/17) installing libxres                                                                                                                     [########################################################################################] 100%
( 7/17) installing libwnck3                                                                                                                    [########################################################################################] 100%
( 8/17) installing epiphany                                                                                                                    [########################################################################################] 100%
( 9/17) installing grilo-plugins                                                                                                               [########################################################################################] 100%
Optional dependencies for grilo-plugins
    gupnp-av: uPnP plugin [installed]
    libgdata: Youtube plugin [installed]
    gnome-online-accounts: Flickr plugin [installed]
    gmime: Podcasts plugin [installed]
    tracker: Tracker plugin [installed]
    libdmapsharing: DMAP sharing plugin [pending]
    json-glib: TMDb plugin [installed]
    avahi: Freebox plugin [installed]
    libmediaart: local-metadata plugin [installed]
    lua: LUA factory plugin [installed]
(10/17) installing gucharmap                                                                                                                   [########################################################################################] 100%
(11/17) installing bijiben                                                                                                                     [########################################################################################] 100%
(12/17) installing gnome-logs                                                                                                                  [########################################################################################] 100%
(13/17) installing gnome-maps                                                                                                                  [########################################################################################] 100%
(14/17) installing libdmapsharing                                                                                                              [########################################################################################] 100%
(15/17) installing gnome-music                                                                                                                 [########################################################################################] 100%
(16/17) installing telepathy-idle                                                                                                              [########################################################################################] 100%
(17/17) installing polari                                                                                                                      [########################################################################################] 100%
```

Now, I ran this command: "sudo pacman -Rs gnome-extra" and I get this output:

```
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: empathy: requires cheese
:: gnome-contacts: requires cheese
:: gnome-control-center: requires gnome-color-manager
:: nautilus: requires nautilus-sendto
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to undo my first action.

Answer (score 5):

See the options for `-R` (remove) in `man pacman`, notably `-u`:

> -u, --unneeded
>            Removes targets that are not required by any other packages. **This is mostly useful when removing a group
>            without using the -c option, to avoid breaking any dependencies**.

To skip dependency checks, you add the `-d` option:

> -d, --nodeps
>            Skips dependency version checks. Package names are still checked. Normally, pacman will always check a
>            package’s dependency fields to ensure that all dependencies are installed and there are no package conflicts
>            in the system. Specify this option twice to skip all dependency checks.

So your final command would be `pacman -Rdsu gnome-extra`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5345QFGq Hmm, this seems tougher than I thought it would be. It seems it wants to remove important applications file-roller, gedit, and evolution.

Comment: @user89930 Remove the `-d` switch for less agressive filtering. Even if you do unistall those packages, they remain in your cache so it is simple enough to reinstall them (without redownloading).

Comment: This is the answer, I ran `pacman -Rdsu gnome-extra` and it removed everything that I wanted gone without a hitch. File-roller, gedit were left in place as was evolution, although I feel like evolution would be a better fit for gnome-extra considering the prevalence of webmail clients these days...